# Q: AWS Redshift: ANALYZE COMPRESSION 'Table Name' - How to save the result set into a table / Join to other Table

Tags: amazon-web-services, performance, amazon-redshift

I am looking for a way to save the result set of an ANALYZE Compression to a table / Joining it to another table in order to automate compression scripts.
Is it Possible and how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always run analyze compression from an external program (bash script is my go to), read the results and store them back up to Redshift with inserts.  This is usually the easiest and fastest way when I run into these type of "no route from leader to compute node" issues on Redshift.  These are often one-off scripts that don't need automation or support.

If I need something programatic I'll usually write a Lambda function (or possibly a python program on an ec2).  Fairly easy and execution speed is high but does require an external tool and some users are not happy running things outside of the database.

If it needs to be completely Redshift internal then I make a procedure that keeps the results of the leader only query in cursor and then loops on the cursor inserting the data into a table.  Basically the same as reading it out and then inserting back in but the data never leaves Redshift.  This isn't too difficult but is slow to execute. Looping on a cursor and inserting 1 row at a time is not efficient.  Last one of these I did took 25 sec for 1000 rows.  It was fast enough for the application but if you need to do this on 100,000 rows you will be waiting a while.  I've never done this with analyze compression before so there could be some issue but definitely worth a shot if this needs to be SQL initiated.